# Pipeline Maven Plugin - Wait until all dependencies where built

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I recently migrated a bunch of Jenkins jobs (that used the Maven Plugin) to a new Jenkins server, using the declarative pipeline approach.
In my pipeline, I described something among this lines:

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        container('my-container') {
            withMaven(options: [pipelineGraphPublisher(lifecycleThreshold: 'install')]){    
                rtMavenRun (
                    pom: 'pom.xml',
                    opts: '-Xms1024m -Xmx1024M',
                    goals: 'clean install',
                    deployerId: "MAVEN_DEPLOYER",
                    resolverId: "MAVEN_RESOLVER"
                )
            }
        }                        
    }
}

stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        withMaven(){
            rtPublishBuildInfo (
                serverId: "myServer"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I use the graph publisher so that upstream jobs trigger downstream builds (build whenever a snapshot dependency is built), as we did with the old Jenkins.

The problem appears in some old legacy projects, that have this dependency structure:

```
                    |- lib A -|
father-of-all-libs -+- lib B -+- project Z
                    |- lib C -|
                    |-  ...  -|
```

In this case, father-of-all-libs will build once, and triggers (correctly) Libs A, B, C, and so on. Each one of them will be built once, and each will trigger a build in project Z, witch is not optimal. I need the build from project Z to wait until all it's currently building dependencies are done, instead of having (in my real worst case scenario) 7 to 8 builds running in parallel.

On my old Jenkins, this was solved by the maven plugin itself. It always waited until all dependencies finished building before actually triggering a build in a downstream project.

I recently added 'disableConcurrentBuilds()' to my options, but it's not really an ideal fix. Firstly because the first lib to finish building still triggers one "unnecessary" build -> the other will be grouped in a second build afterwards. Secondly, because if there are multiple commits (in a short amount of time) directly to the project, those changes will also be grouped.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins, or the pipeline plugin, to wait until all upstream dependencies are finished before triggering a build?

Comment: Belong all those libs to only project Z?

Comment: No, these libs are shared across many projects. Some use one or two, others use more. It's a very large organization.